# Can we use Bitwise operator "|" with strpos in php?

Tags: php, strpos

Can we use Bitwise operator "|" with strpos in php? 
 I need to check if **a0,a1,a2,a5** strings are exists in the given $status variable.
 My code is given bellow.My code will return values(position) only when the status variable have **value=a0 or a1 or a2 or a5**.It will return false when $status='a1 test string.

```
 $status='a1 test string';
 echo strpos("|a0|a1|a2|a5|", $status);
```

Comment: Question is: how is defined what _part_ of that status string you actually want to search for?

Comment: I need to search if the string( $status) contains a1 OR a2 OR a0 OR a5

Comment: And if the status string is something like "a2 is not the same as a5 or a3!"?

Comment: The status string may contain strings with a1 OR a2 OR a5 Or a0.  ..  The above code just used to check if the status string contain any these strings(a1,a0,a2,a5)

Comment: Sure, but it will give you false positives.

Comment: false positives?I didnt get the point .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140227/discussion-between-user1752065-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. [Documentation](http://php.net/strpos) does not mention anything remotely similar:

> `strpos` — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in
>   a string
>
> Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of `needle` in the
>   `haystack` string.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `haystack` The string to search in.
>
> `needle` If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and
>   applied as the ordinal value of a character.
>
> `offset` If specified, search will start this number of characters
>   counted from the beginning of the string. If the offset is negative,
>   the search will start this number of characters counted from the end
>   of the string.

In fact, it wouldn't make much sense to implement such feature since you already have a full-fledged [regular expression](http://php.net/preg_match) engine:

```
$has_substrings = (bool)preg_match('/a0|a1|a2|a5/u', $status);
```

Comment: I found the above code in an open source project. So this will conside "|a0|a1|a2|a5|" as a single string r8?

Comment: @user1752065 r8? I don't have the faintest idea of what you're talking about—remember we cannot read you mind ;-) If you have questions about certain software, you should ask them explicitly (and of course provide some context).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this. Here `|` means `or`

```
<?php 
$status='a1 test string';

if(preg_match("/\b(a0|a1|a2|a5)\b/", $status))
{
    echo "Matched";
}
```

Comment: I found this code in an open source project(Open EMR). Is this code is correct? $status='a1 test string';
echo strpos("|a0|a1|a2|a5|", $status);

Comment: @user1752065 Let check for other options as well

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use Bitwise operator "|" with strpos in php?

as a Bitwise operator `|` - **No**

as a literal symbol `|` - **Yes**

Comment: So this '(strpos("|a0|a1|a2|a5|", $status))' will conside "|a0|a1|a2|a5|" as a single string r8?

Comment: I don't know what is `r8` in your case, but, yes, exactly, `strpos` considers `"|a0|a1|a2|a5|"` as a single string

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with a single string search. You need to use either a regular expression which can test for multiple options at once, or you need to iterate over your search terms.

Sahil Gulati gave a simple example for a regular expression based approach.

Here is a simple iteration based approach:

```
<?php
$status = 'a1 test string';
$search = explode('|', substr("|a0|a1|a2|a5|", 1, -1));
// would be much easier to start with an array of search tokens right away: 
// $search = ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a5'];

$result = false;
array_walk($search, function($token) use ($status, &$result) {
    $result = (FALSE!==strpos($status, $token)) ? true : $result;
});
var_dump($result);
```